# GWT, superdevmode, and an extra Tomcat port

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gwt

Based on samples found in the net, I developped a GWT webapp....that works fine (so far) when it is started in superdevmode from eclipse (through Jetty).
A browser can access my webpage from local/remote computer (bindaddress=0.0.0.0).

Issues appear when trying to deploy it with TomCat. Indeed, the webpage is accessible, but at some point, there is a redirection to port 9786. I guess this is a normal situation since it is built in superdevmode? If I set the development mode in Eclipse to Classic mode, it doesn't even work in Eclipse.

I thought having a web server listening on port 9786 is not a proper implementation. So, I am trying to get rid of this port (probably a matter of dev mode).

What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to test your GWT App on an external server with SuperDevMode?

Comment: How did you deploy to your Tomcat? Did you compile (GWT Compilation I mean) your project before deploying it?